# Checking if number of objects is < 1 in PHP object array

Tags: php

I am trying to check whether the number of items in an object is less than one like this:

```
if ( count($trailhead_list->o < 1 ) )
```

It always returns true even if there is some items there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an error in your brackets, it should read like that:

```
if ( count($trailhead_list->o) < 1)
```